# how to design model classes in java project

Tags: java, model

I am new to jsp. I want to do a test project to get familiar with it.

The project I have selected to do is to design a website that people can register on and make a resume for themselves.

Each person who is registered can define some projects that he has worked on before.

For example, if I register with the user name **SHT** and define **PROJECTA** and **PROJECTB**, it means that these projects should be displayed in my resume.

By the way, I want to use the MVC design.

My problem is that when I want to design model classes, I don't know which approach is the best from the following scenarios:

1- The first thing that came to my mind was that, I can have a class for *Users* which contains **UserId** and **UserName** and ...
I need another class for *Projects* which contains **ProjectName** and **ProjectId**, and again another class for **UserProject** which has **UserId**, **ProjectId** to be able to find which project belongs to a specific user.

In this example I have a User Object from User class that UserId is 1 and UserName is 'SHT'.

> I have 2 objects from project class :
>
> OBJECT1{ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = "PROJECTA"}
>
> OBJECT2{ProjectId = 2, ProjectName = "PROJECTB"}
>
> and again I have these objects from UserProject :
>
> OBJECT1{UserId = 1, ProjectId = 1} ,
>
> OBJECT2 {UserId =1, ProjectId = 2}

2- The second way, I can have a class for *Projects* that has these fields : **ProjectId**, **ProjectName**. I have again another class for *Users* with these fields: **UserId**, **UserName** and a list of the user's projects.

forexample in this way I have :

> 2 objects from Projects :
>
> OBJECT1{ ProjectId = 1 , ProjectName = "PROJECTA"}
>
> OBJECTB { ProjectId = 2, ProjectName = "PROOJECTB"}
>
> and an object from User :
>
> USER1 { UserId = 1  , UserNAme = "SHT", ListOfProjects =  {ProjectId = 1,ProjectId = 2}}

These were the 2 ways that came to my mind. But I don't know which one is better in this situation. 
I think maybe the first way is better, because later I might want to add the feature that every user can register for some projects and each user can have a list of skills and so on. With these features I think maybe the first way is easier to handle.

Can anyone please help me to find out which one is better?

If you think there is a better way, I will really appreciate it.

thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: The answer to your question is really based on what you think would be more appropriate. On one hand the second method would allow you to easily add more projects to a user after that user has been created, and that one also has username while the first one doesn't. I really am still not totally sure what you are going for with this project, so it's really hard to say which one is "better".

Comment: @BenjaminLowry thanks for your comment. I'm afraid if the second way make my code complex. on the other hand, I'm afraid if the first one make my code dirty.

Comment: Well I would suggest using the second method because it allows you to have the capacity to do more in the future. The drawbacks of complexity really won't impact you severely in the future, while using an overly simple method could force you to rework your entire project or just prohibit you from achieving certain functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say there are 3 points you want to judge a solution on.

- Storage space
- Search time for project -> users
- Search time for user -> projects

For your two solutions the storage space is asymptotically equal, for every UserProject object in solution 1 there is one item in the ListOfProjects of some user in solution 2.

For doing a project -> users search they also behave equally well since in solution 2 you'd have to go through every user and see what projects they worked on which is the same as going through every UserProject in solution 1.

For doing a user -> projects search solution 2 is alot faster since it can directly get a list from the user that has the answer.

I'm gonna propose 2 other solutions myself too, lets call them solution 3 and solution 4.

**Solution 3:** The same as solution 2 but the other way around, projects store a list of users working on them.

**Solution 4:** Solution 2 and solution 3 combined, users store on which projects they are working and projects store which users are working on them.

**Pros and cons of all solutions:**

- Solution 1

  - Small storage
  - Slow project -> users search
  - Slow user -> projects search
- Solution 2

  - Small storage
  - Slow project -> users search
  - Fast user -> projects search
- Solution 3

  - Small storage
  - Fast project -> users search
  - Slow users -> project search
- Solution 4

  - Big storage
  - Fast project -> users search
  - Fast user -> projects search

I'd say solution 1 is definitly the worst option available, the others depend on your situation.

Comment: Really thanks for your perfect explanation. By the way I have a question from solution 4: what do you mean by "projects store which users are working on them."? in this project, I will have to add a feature that users request for doing a project. so, by "projects store which users are working on them." do you mean that I should save these users who have requested for doing project in Project class? Or you mean I should save the user who have created the project in this class?

Comment: Both, for direct project -> users storage you have to store every user that is somehow connected to the project in the project object, just as you would have to store every project that is somehow connected to the user in the user object for direct user -> projects.